I want to understand test result format of Junit in VS Code
In VS Code, using JUnit. I am testing addition() method of calculator class. I have used assertEqual method to compare expected result and actual result.
This is my code for test method:
@Test
    public void testAdd_Positive() {
       
        int result = c.addition(5, 10);
        assertEquals(15, result);
    }
Test run successfully. and output is as below:
[test reault in VS code](https://i.sstatic.net/fQYoKF6t.jpg)

%TESTC  1 v2
%TSTTREE1,testAdd_Positive(MYJAVAPROJECT.test),false,1,false,-1,testAdd_Positive(MYJAVAPROJECT.test),,
%TESTS  1,testAdd_Positive(MYJAVAPROJECT.test)

%TESTE  1,testAdd_Positive(MYJAVAPROJECT.test)

%RUNTIME26

I am not able to understand this result. So can anyone help explain what this result says?
*%TSTTREE1,testAdd_Positive(MYJAVAPROJECT.test),false,1,false,-1,testAdd_Positive(MYJAVAPROJECT.test)

